# Which canonical URL for language subdirectories with gTLD?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, multilingual

If I have pages with same content and different languages, for example:

```
https://www.example.com/en/page/
https://www.example.com/de/page/
https://www.example.com/fr/page/
```

What will be the canonical for each? I’m a little bit lost in all theories. Do I pick one like below or is there a better approach? Is translation not duplication?

English page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.example.com/de/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.example.com/fr/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

German page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/de/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.example.com/de/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.example.com/fr/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

French page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/fr/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.example.com/de/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.example.com/fr/page/" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/page/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Comment: Your option is fine, just fix the hreflang="de" on the fr-page.

Comment: That's perfect. And translation is not duplication, you should however ALWAYS refrain from publishing machine translated pages.